# How can I test a QAbstractListModel via Qt Quick Test?

Tags: c++, qt, testing, qml

I have written a [`QAbstractListModel`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) class to expose data from my library to QML.  It seems to work correctly together with the QML `ListView` component, but I'd like to write some tests for it to ensure it continues to behave.

I've been testing other parts of my QML module via [Qt Quick Test](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-qtquicktest.html), but couldn't work out how to access the model directly from QML.  I'm after simple things like checking the row count, and accessing role data values for arbitrary rows in the model.

Is this actually possible, or would I need to write the tests in C++?

Comment: since you have model written in C++ then writing test for it with C++ is more natural IMO. I would look for some code patterns how to test data models.

Comment: As I said in my question, I wrote the model class with the intent of exposing it to QML.  So it seems natural to write tests in QML to demonstrate that it works as intended.  I realise that it is possible to test models from C++, but since I've been able to test the rest of my QML module from QML, I would like to test this part from QML too if possible.

Comment: QML is UI, QAbstractItemModel - is data. So you may write tests to model.

Comment: I am aware of what QML is: the code I've written is a QML binding for a library, so I'm asking whether I can test it from QML/JS using the standard QML testing framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a subject that I always have to look up myself, and I'm still a bit unsure, so there may be better ways than what I suggest. Anyway, it seems that `QAbstractItemModel` doesn't provide the functions that you're trying to test. I can think of two ways to get around that.

## Add them yourself

```
#include <QtGui/QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QDebug>
#include "qtquick2applicationviewer.h"

#include "QAbstractListModel"

class Model : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Model() {}

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        return mList.size();
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const{
        if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= mList.size()) {
            return QVariant();
        }
        return mList.at(index.row());
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE QVariant get(int index) {
        return data(createIndex(index, 0));
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void append(QVariant element) {
        beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), mList.size() + 1, mList.size() + 1);
        mList.append(element.toMap().value("name").toString());
        endInsertRows();
    }
private:
    QList<QString> mList;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QtQuick2ApplicationViewer viewer;
    Model model;
    viewer.rootContext()->setContextProperty("model", &model);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/quick/main.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Here's a small hack of a QML test case:

```
import QtQuick 2.2

Item {
    width: 360
    height: 360

    Component.onCompleted: {
        model.append({name: "blah"});
        console.assert(model.get(0) === "blah");
    }
}
```

## Use [QQmlListProperty](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html)

This is only useful if your model is or can be wrapped by a `QObject` subclass, as it is, as its name suggests, used as a property of an object. It's useful for it's convenience, but is less flexible than the first option, as it can only store `QObject`-derived object pointers. I won't go into details on this, as I'm assuming that this is not relevant for your use case.

You can find more information below:

[Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html)

Answer (score 2):

I know this topic is old, but anyway here is your answer.

Once your [QAbstractListModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html) is defined on cpp side, you access delegate's roles via delegate's property:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtTest 1.0

Item {
    width: 1    // the minimum size of visible compoment
    height: 1   // the minimum size of visible compoment

    ListView {
        id: testView
        model: yourModelId
        delegate: Item {
            property variant dataModel: model
        }
    }

    TestCase {
        when: windowShown

        function test_dataModelReadDelegate() {
            testView.currentIndex = 0
            testView.currentItem.dataModel["yourRole"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Be careful, [ListView](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) must be visible (also [TestCase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qttest-testcase.html) waits until windowShown is true), otherwise the delegates will not be created ([TestCase](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qttest-testcase.html) itself is invisible component).

And for some reason, when the root Item has no size, I'll get warning about invalid component size.

Comment: How do you expose yourModelId to qml from c++ side? All I have is the quick_test_main function?